# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem '2.12.3' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

When I try to run:

> gem install sprockets 2.12.3

It says I have successfully installed sprockets but I have an error:

> Successfully installed sprockets-2.12.3
>
> Parsing documentation for sprockets-2.12.3
>
> Done installing documentation for sprockets after 1 seconds
>
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '2.12.3' (>= 0) in any repository
>
> 1 gem installed

I was wondering whether anyone knew how to fix this problem??

Thank you.

Comment: Please run `gem help install` and read the output. Look for `-v, --version VERSION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify version with `-v` flag

```
gem install sprockets -v 2.12.3
```

Also depending on ruby version you're using, this might be helpful:

```
gem install sprockets:2.12.3
```

If you have another version of the gem already installed, you might want uninstall it first, `gem uninstall`